# How to force step order on css animation?

Tags: css, css-animations, css-transitions, css-transforms

I have this small code working good:

```
#image {
  height: 32px;
  width: 32px;  
  background: url('./media/man.png') 32px 0px;
  animation: autoRotate 1s steps(4) infinite;
  transform: scale(5);
  image-rendering: pixelated;
}
```

and this for the animation

```
@keyframes autoRotate {    
 0% {
  background-position: 32px 0px;
 } 
 100% {
  background-position: 32px 128px;
 }  
}
```

The think is, cause the sprite was made how was made, what i see is:

The sprite looking to left->right->back->front

I want rotation like left->front->right->back

im trying to put a 50% step but fails

i can't find the way to declare step-by-step my this-4-steps

```
i need to declare something like:

step1: background-position: 32px 0px;
step2: background-position: 32px 64px;
step3: background-position: 32px 96px;
step4: background-position: 32px 32px;
```

All what i try, fails XD. My brain logic was to put kayframes on 0% 25% 50% 75% and 100% with this rules, but fail.

any idea how to make this without changing the sprite png?  thanks.